# Livewire en laravel 8

Tags: laravel-8

Hola buen día estoy trabajando con un sistema hecho con laravel y me encuentro con el siguiente problema.
Realizando los paso para crear el proyecto

```
laravel new proyecto --jet
```

También trabaje con la creación de la base de datos con Heidi  y luego realice las migraciones para poder levantar y trabajar con jetstream
Luego realice las migraciones

```
php artisan migrate
```

todo funciono con normalidad pero el momento de ingresar como usuario debería de aparecer la barra para poder actualizar contrase;a y realizar algunos cambios
[image: Aparece @livewareStyles y @liveware[Navigation-menu]]

Revisando algunos post menciona que se debe de instalar usando el comando `composer require livewire\livewire`, esto no funciono, alguien sabe alguna otra solución

Comment: ¿Cuando instalaste jetstream qué stack elegiste?

Comment: Parece que no has completado los pasos, revisa con la guía oficial: https://jetstream.laravel.com/2.x/installation.html

Comment: Resuelto. Gracias

Comment: Publica tu solución